# How to do hex8 encoding in c?

Tags: c

I am trying to encode a string in hex8 using c. The script I have right now is:

```
int hex8 (char str) {
 str = printf("%x", str);
 if(strlen(str) == 1) {
  return printf("%s", "0", str);
 } else {
  return str;
 }
}
```

In this function, I will need to add a 0 ahead of the string if the length is less than 1. I don't know why I'm getting:

> passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

The second line is a problem:

```
str = printf("%x", str);
```

`printf` outputs text to `stdout`, and returns an integer representing the number of characters that it output, not the actual value that was printed. You should replace this line with a call to `sprintf` instead, to load the output into `str`:

```
sprintf(str, "%x", str);
```

You can read about the various standard output functions here: [Formatted Output Functions](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Output-Functions.html)

Note that `sprintf` returns the number of characters that it stored into `str`, so you can actually use this to check whether you need to add the `0`, instead of using `strlen` at all, like this:

```
if (sprintf(str, "%x", str) == 1)
{
...
```

Comment: Except that `sprintf(str, "%x", str)` will try to store it's results in the location pointed to by `(char *)str`, but `str` is of type `char`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what hex8 encoding is, but it looks like you're trying to turn a `char` into a two-byte hex string?  In that case, you don't need anything as complicated as you have there.  Just do something like this:

```
char hexstring[3];
char character = 'f';

sprintf(hexstring, "%02x", character);
```

After that code fragment, `hexstring` will be `"66"`.  If you have a whole string, something like this should work (assuming you've allocated appropriate memory before calling the function):

```
void string2hex(char *hex, char *in)
{
    while (*in)
    {
       hex += sprintf(hex, "%02x", *in);
       in++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I went with "explain the issues he's having with his solution", but I suppose "show him the right way to do it" is good too. :b

Comment: You can easily determine the length of the string you will need to store a string as hex by `size_t hex_str_len = 1+ (2 *strlen(str) );` as long as `str` is a null terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter str is a char.  strlen expects a char const * argument.  From the context it would seem you need to change the prototype to char *str.

EDIT: You will also need to change the function return type to char *.